# ValueError: Cannot assign "'26 Balkanskaya Street'": "paidparking.adress" must be a "Parking" instance

Tags: python, django

I have a model `paidparking`

```
 class paidparking(models.Model):
        adress = models.ForeignKey(Parking, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        carnumber = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        amountoftime = models.IntegerField()
        price = models.FloatField()
        telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        email = models.EmailField(,null=True,blank=True )
        datetimepaidparking = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        expirationdate = models.DateField(null=True)
        expirationtime = models.TimeField(null=True)
        enddateandtime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Model Parking:

```
class Parking(models.Model):
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    starttime = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,null=True)
    endtime = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,null=True)
    minimaltimeforpayment = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    numberofavailableseats = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tickets = models.ManyToManyField('tickets', blank=True)
```

I have a page on the site where there is a form. Through this form I save the data to the model

```
class paidparkingForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = paidparking
      fields = ['adress','carnumber','amountoftime', 'price', 'email','telephone','expirationdate','expirationtime','enddateandtime']
      widgets = {
          'adress': forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control form", "id": "exampleFormControlSelect1"}),
          'carnumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control form-control-lg form"}),
          'amountoftime': forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class": "number form-control form-control-lg form", "disabled": 1}),
          'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class": "form-control form-control-lg form", "readonly": 0}),
          'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class": "form-control form-control-lg form"}),
          'telephone': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control form-control-lg form"}),
          'expirationdate': forms.DateInput(attrs={"type": "date","class": "form form-control form-control-lg", "disabled": 1}),
          'expirationtime': forms.TimeInput(attrs={"type": "time", "class": "form form-control form-control-lg", "disabled": 1}),
          'enddateandtime':  forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form form-control form-control-lg", "readonly": 0}),
      }
```

How do I save data to the model directly from the function?

I do this

```
def save_payment_parking(request):
    adress = request.GET["adress"]
    carnumber = request.GET["car_number"]
    amountoftime = request.GET["amount_of_time"]
    price = request.GET["price"]
    telephone = request.GET["telephone"]
    expirationdate = request.GET["date_time_paid_parking"]
    expirationtime = request.GET["expiration_time"]
    enddateandtime = request.GET["end_date_and_time"]
    save_payment_parking = paidparking
    save_payment_parking(adress=adress
                         ,carnumber=carnumber,amountoftime=amountoftime,price=price,telephone=telephone,expirationdate=expirationdate,expirationtime=expirationtime,enddateandtime=enddateandtime).save()
```

But I get an error

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'26 Balkanskaya Street'": "paidparking.adress" must be a "Parking" instance.
```

I have a key inserted in the adress field from the Parking adress field. How do I make it so that my line is inserted in the adress field? The adress field in the Parking model has the value of my row. Perhaps you need to somehow determine the id of the record where my string is equal to the value in the adress field of the Parking model and insert this id

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to create the `Parking` before creating the `paidparking`?

You have a foreign key to an object that doesn't exist and are trying to set the object to a string.

```py
def save_payment_parking(request):
    adress = request.GET["adress"]
    carnumber = request.GET["car_number"]
    amountoftime = request.GET["amount_of_time"]
    price = request.GET["price"]
    telephone = request.GET["telephone"]
    expirationdate = request.GET["date_time_paid_parking"]
    expirationtime = request.GET["expiration_time"]
    enddateandtime = request.GET["end_date_and_time"]
    parking = Parking.objects.get_or_create(address=address)[0] # << or something
    save_payment_parking = paidparking
    save_payment_parking(adress=parking,carnumber=carnumber,amountoftime=amountoftime,price=price,telephone=telephone,expirationdate=expirationdate,expirationtime=expirationtime,enddateandtime=enddateandtime).save()
```

Edit - I added `objects`. Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: I get an error `AttributeError: type object 'Parking' has no attribute 'get_or_create'`

Comment: I edited the answer. You need "objects" in there.